# How I can make text field behave like password field through input masking?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I dont want to save password for my site. So, I tried with autocomplete = 'off', autocomplete="new-password" but it is not working. Now I come up with input masking idea. So could you please let me know how I can change each character enter in text field to behave like password * character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991469/chrome-firefox-autocomplete-new-password-not-working

Answer (score 0):

here is an example.

```css
.test {
  text-security: disc;
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
  -moz-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one but I think this will only work in Chrome.

```js
document.getElementById("input").oninput = ( function(event) {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
});
```

```css
#input {
-webkit-text-security: disc;
-moz-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="input">
<p id="text"></p>
```

Thanks and best regards!